# How to get last N week data in different year

Tags: sql, db2

I need to get last 6 weeks data from some table, right now the logic that I use is this

```
WEEK([date column]) BETWEEN WEEK(NOW()) - 6 AND WEEK(NOW())
```

It run as I want, but January is near and I realize that this query will not working as it is. I try to run my query on 15th January 2022, I only get data from 1st January to 15th January when I use my logic.

```
TGL           MINGGU_KE
2022-01-01  |     1
2022-01-02  |     2
2022-01-03  |     2
2022-01-04  |     2
2022-01-05  |     2
2022-01-06  |     2
2022-01-07  |     2
2022-01-08  |     2
2022-01-09  |     3
2022-01-10  |     3
2022-01-11  |     3
2022-01-12  |     3
2022-01-13  |     3
2022-01-14  |     3
2022-01-15  |     3
```

Can I get the last 6 weeks data including last year?

This is my dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/o9BeAFJF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can round the dates to the first day of the week using [`ROUND`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-round), [`TRUNC`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-truncate-trunc) or [`THIS_WEEK`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-this-week)

```
WITH
SEARCH_WEEK (TGL) AS (
  VALUES date '2020-12-01'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT tgl + 1 DAY FROM SEARCH_WEEK WHERE tgl < CURRENT date
  ),
BASE_DATE (base_date) AS (
    VALUES date '2022-01-15'
),
OPTIONS (OPTION, OPTION_BASE_DATE) AS (
    SELECT OPTION, option_base_date FROM base_date CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
        VALUES
        ('ROUND D', ROUND(base_date, 'D')),
        ('ROUND IW', ROUND(base_date, 'IW')),
        ('ROUND W', ROUND(base_date, 'W')),
        ('ROUND WW', ROUND(base_date, 'WW')),
        ('TRUNC D', TRUNC(base_date, 'D')),
        ('TRUNC IW', TRUNC(base_date, 'IW')),
        ('TRUNC W', TRUNC(base_date, 'W')),
        ('TRUNC WW', TRUNC(base_date, 'WW')),
        ('THIS_WEEK', THIS_WEEK(base_date)),
        ('THIS_WEEK + 1 DAY', THIS_WEEK(base_date) + 1 DAY)
    ) a (OPTION, OPTION_BASE_DATE)
)
SELECT
    OPTION,
    MIN(TGL) BEGIN,
    max(tgl) END,
    dayname(MIN(TGL)) day_BEGIN,
    dayname(max(tgl)) day_end,
    days_between(max(tgl), min(tgl)) + 1 duration_in_days
FROM
  SEARCH_WEEK
  CROSS JOIN options
WHERE
  TGL BETWEEN option_base_date - 35 DAYS AND option_base_date + 6 DAYS
GROUP BY OPTION
```

| OPTION | BEGIN | END | DAY_BEGIN | DAY_END | DURATION_IN_DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ROUND D | 2021-12-12 | 2022-01-22 | Sunday | Saturday | 42 |
| ROUND IW | 2021-12-13 | 2022-01-23 | Monday | Sunday | 42 |
| ROUND W | 2021-12-11 | 2022-01-21 | Saturday | Friday | 42 |
| ROUND WW | 2021-12-11 | 2022-01-21 | Saturday | Friday | 42 |
| THIS_WEEK | 2021-12-05 | 2022-01-15 | Sunday | Saturday | 42 |
| THIS_WEEK + 1 DAY | 2021-12-06 | 2022-01-16 | Monday | Sunday | 42 |
| TRUNC D | 2021-12-05 | 2022-01-15 | Sunday | Saturday | 42 |
| TRUNC IW | 2021-12-06 | 2022-01-16 | Monday | Sunday | 42 |
| TRUNC W | 2021-12-11 | 2022-01-21 | Saturday | Friday | 42 |
| TRUNC WW | 2021-12-11 | 2022-01-21 | Saturday | Friday | 42 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LAottwG0)

Answer (score 0):

you can use dateadd to get first day of week six weeks ago like this:

Select * from tableName
where [dateColumn] between dateadd(WEEK,-6,getdate()) and getdate()

Comment: I think DB2 is not supporting DATEADD function

Comment: The question is for Db2, your answers appears to be aimed at SQL-server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEADD to get last 6 weeks of data as follows:

```
Select * from [TableName] where [DateColumn] between
DATEADD(WEEK,-6,GETDATE()) and GETDATE();
```

Comment: The question is for Db2, your answers appears to be aimed at SQL-server?